# std::copy causing Run-Time Check Failure #2

Tags: c++

The code where the error occurs:

```cpp
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef std::vector<BYTE> BUFFER;

RequestInfo JsonRequestPacketDeserializer::createRequestInfo(BUFFER& buffer)
{

    RequestType type = static_cast<RequestType>(buffer[0]);
    uint32_t dataLen = 0;
    std::copy(&buffer[1], &buffer[4], &dataLen);

    if (buffer.size() - 5 != dataLen)
    {
        throw FailedToDeserializeRequest();
    }

    return RequestInfo(type, std::time(nullptr), std::vector<unsigned char>(buffer.begin() + 5, buffer.begin() + 5 + dataLen));
}
```

At the end of this function it throws:

`Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'dataLen' was corrupted.`

I found out that the error is being caused by `std::copy` since removing that line stopped the error from occurring.

From what I know:
`dataLen` is 4 bytes, so should be the amount being copied. Meaning no 'overflow' should happen, but it does. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `buffer[i]` is copied into `*(&dataLen + i - 1)` for i = 1, 2, 3, 4. That causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `std::time(nullptr)` has really bad resolution - better use [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). `typedef unsigned char BYTE;` - [std::byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) exists, but if you *insist*, I'd suggest `using BYTE = unsigned char;` as a more readable alternative.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Can you explain how? From my logic: let's take i=1. In that case: `*(&dataLen + 1 - 1)` == `*(&dataLen)` the same as `dataLen[0]`? Still in range. If we take i=4 we get `dataLen[3]` which should also be okay, shouldn't it?

Comment: `dataLen` is a variable, not an array. How could writing into `dataLen[3]` be okay?

Comment: It copies 3 bytes, not 4.  Puts you further away from an obvious buffer overflow.  I'll randomly guess that the buffer contains big-endian data, causing the constructor to blow the stack.  Hmm.  Use the debugger to see what happens to the stack frame, specifically the 0xcc bytes before and after &dataLen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buffer[i]` is copied into `*(&dataLen + i - 1)` for i = 1, 2, 3, 4. That causes undefined behavior. You want

```
uint32_t dataLen = buffer[1];
for (std::size_t i = 2; i != 5; ++i) {
    dataLen = (dataLen << 8) + buffer[i];
}
```

This loop copies 4 single bytes into one variable with 4 byte size where `buffer[1]` is the most significant byte. You can also

```
uint32_t dataLen = buffer[4];
for (std::size_t i = 3; i != 0; --i) {
    dataLen = (dataLen << 8) + buffer[i];
}
```

where `buffer[1]` is the least significant byte

Comment: I tried your suggestion, got a strange result. My buffer looks like this: [buffer screen shot](https://i.imgur.com/ZjnLGNO.png). `dataLen` should be 40. but I get  671088640. I think it should be done in reverse?

Comment: @RoyiLevy You are trying to copy 4 bytes into `dataLen` and the result should be 40??? That only possible if three of the 4 bytes are zero. What's the meaning of `dataLen`?

Comment: That's the case. indexes 2-4 are 0, index 1 is 40.

Comment: So `buffer[1]` is the least significant byte. Use the second loop.

Comment: Gives error "canot deduce auto type"  and "C++ no operator "+" matches these operands  operand types are: std::vector<uint_8t> + int". Since buffer is vector I tried doing `buffer.being() + 3` but this also gives "no operator "+" matches..."

Answer (score 0):

`std::copy` takes 3 parameters: `first`, `last` and `d_first`. It copies `[first, last)` interval to the range beginning at `d_first`.

In this case, `first` and `last` are legitimate (and mean that it would copy 3 elements of buffer: buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]), but the third parameter, whose type is `int32_t*` pointer to integer variable, is wrong.  If it would be `BYTE*`, it would copy 3 bytes to 3 bytes.  If it would be `int32_t*`, but point to array of at least 3 integers, it would copy 3 bytes to 3 integers.